# Eclipse RCP CoolBar Action FORCE_TEXT

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-kepler

```
   </extension>
       <extension
             point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
          <menuContribution
                allPopups="false"
                locationURI="toolbar:com.*****.*****.ui.main.toolbar?after=workbenchActions">
             <command
                   commandId="org.eclipse.ui.file.save"
                   disabledIcon="icons/save24x24_disabled.png"
                   icon="icons/save24x24.png"
                   label="Save"
                   mode="FORCE_TEXT"
                   style="push">
             </command>
          </menuContribution>
   </extension>
```

I'm pointing to the workbench's `Save` command using a menu command, because I want to change the icon and force the text underneath it.

Icon works fine, but the text won't show (it should say *Save* below the icon, because I set the mode to `FORCE_TEXT` and have a label present).

Is it a bug, or a limitation of the framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running Eclipse 4.2 or 4.3 this looks like Eclipse bug [399065](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=399065)